# Bugzilla vs Mantis: Does Bugzilla offer a "Report/Screen" with varius status side by side?

Tags: bugzilla, mantis

Does Bugzilla have a similar report/view as shown below. What are the rough steps in bugzilla to create such a report/view?

Update: What I am Looking for is a reporttype/view that allows to show categorized (like below) N items (N should be a number that i can set) of the respective type, like "last N resloved", "last N newest" etc...

Background I am comparing bugzilla and mantis...

Thanks very much!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do what you are asking in Bugzilla without customization.